# AJAX document.getElementById not working when pass through parameters

Tags: php, ajax, getelementbyid

I'm writing an AJAX code that gets input from the users, and outputs the results, and it works when I'm setting the variable called text inside the function, but when I'm passing it through it doesn't work. Please take a look, I've taken all the irrelevant codes out, so it's short.

Code when I'm not passing it through the parameter:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

function process(){

  text = 'userInput';
  food = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById(text).value);

}

</script>

<html>
<body onload="process()">
</body>
</html>
```

Code when I'm passing it through the parameter:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

function process(text){

  food = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById(text).value);

}

</script>

<html>
<body onload="process('userInput')">
</body>
</html>
```

I did document.write both times to make sure that the variable is really 'userInput', and both times, whether I'm passing it through or setting it inside the function, it printed out fine, so I'm not sure what the problem is. If you know what's wrong, please let me know. Thank you.

The whole code:

> functions.js:

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

//****************************************************************AJAX

function createXmlHttpRequestObject() {
    var xmlHttp;

    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    } else {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }

    if (!xmlHttp)
        alert("Not xmlHttp!")else
            return xmlHttp;
}

//****************************************************************AJAX

function process(IDName, passTo, output) {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 0 || xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        get = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById(IDName).value);
        xmlHttp.open("GET", passTo + get, true);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse(output);
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    } else {
        setTimeout('process()', 1000);
    }
}

//****************************************************************AJAX

function handleServerResponse(output) {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
            xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
            message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
            document.getElementById(output).innerHTML = message;
            setTimeout('process()', 1000);
        } else {
            alert('xmlHttp.status does not equal 200!');
        }
    }
}
```

> foodstore.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';

echo '<response>';
$food = $_GET['food'];
$foodArray = array('tuna','bacon','beef','ham');

if(in_array($food,$foodArray))
    echo 'We do have '.$food.'!';
elseif ($food=='')
    echo 'Enter a food';
else
   echo 'Sorry punk we dont sell no '.$food.'!';

echo '</response>';
?>
```

> test5.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="process('userInput','foodstore.php?food=','underInput')">
    <h3>The Chuff Bucker</h3>
    Enter the food you would like to order:
    <input type="text" id="userInput" />
    <div id="underInput" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have an item with the `id="userInput"`, so `food` (it should be `var food = ....`) will be undefined.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Do you know why none of the two codes I'm showing have the id="userInput", and while one works the other one doesn't? It because I'm not showing those codes here. I'm not showing them, because I just want to show the relevant codes to point out the problem.

Comment: If you do not show the thing with the `id="userInput"` you're failing to show all of the relevant code.

Comment: The two codes should work identically. You're obviously doing something else differently between the two versions.

Comment: @barmar I'm not. That's the only thing I'm change between them two. If you want, I can post the entire code for you.

Comment: Yes, please post the entire code. There's no way we can debug for you when we only get snippets.

Comment: @barmar the entire code is above.

Comment: That code is nothing like the original code! What are those `setTimeout` calls for? And why aren't they passing any arguments to `process()`?

Comment: @barmar Thank you. It's working now. It wasn't working because the setTimeouts wasn't passing any arguements to process(). It's so if it isn't ready to communicate with server, it waits for 1 seconds before trying again, so it doesn't overload the server. again thank you. i will accept your answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're performing `handleServerResponse(output);` when you assign the `onreadystatechange` handler, not when the event occurs. You need to delay calling the function until the event occurs:

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    handleServerResponse(output);
};
```

Comment: That didn't do anything. Did you try out the codes?

Comment: Why are you doing the AJAX request when the page is loaded? You're not waiting for the user to enter anything into the input field.

Comment: instead of using onload, is there another method i can use?

Comment: Use `onchange` in the `input` element.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran this test on your (modified) code and it worked as expected.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

function process(text){
alert(text);
  food = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById(text).value);
alert(food);
}

</script>

<html>
<body onload="process('userInput')">
<input id="userInput" value="yummy" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: An answer should show how to fix the problem. Saying that it works should just be a comment.

Comment: You could post a link to jsfiddle.'

Comment: Right. It prints it out. But it actually don't work when you're getting it by id. Try setting the variable yummy to the input text, and it won't work.

Comment: @7sin There is no variable `yummy`, that's just the value of the input.